# Odoo C# connector can't find the table by name

Tags: c#, odoo

I'm working on a C# application that connects to Odoo and should get/write some data.
And I use the OdooJsonRpcClient library for it:

https://github.com/Intechnity-com/OdooJsonRpcClient

All works fine. But I have a problem with the connection to one table. In PostgreSQL, it has the name "res_partner_res_partner_category_rel". As I saw in the documentation we should use the same name as in the database, but replace the "_" symbols with ".". But in the case of this table when I try to get/set data and use "res.partner.res.partner.category.rel" the OdooJsonRpcClient returns an error that current table doesn't exist in the database.

Why does it happen? And how can I find the correct name of all table names in the Odoo to be able to use them?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to improve the title to be more descriptive of the problem and question, rather than just tag names. See [ask] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tables are generated automatically and you probably have to guess which model implements a field using those generated tables. In your example it's a many-to-many relationship between models `res.partner` and `res.partner.category`. This relationship is only implemented as field in model `res.partner` and not in `res.partner.category`.

The table you've found is the typical associative table for many-to-many relationships. These table's names typically end with `_rel`.

IIRC Using JSON-RPC should work just fine. For example make a `read` on `res.partner` either with all fields (empty list/array) or with field `category_id`. You should get a list/array of IDs of table `res_partner_category` (if there are relations).

Comment: Thanks, that's helped. I've added the "category_id" property to my model that describes the "res.partner" table record and this property got the correct value. But in the database, there is no such property in the "res.partner" table. How can I know what name of property/column should I use?

Comment: You can search for references in the postgres db. For example looking into `res_partner` table definition in postgres you can find: `TABLE "res_partner_res_partner_category_rel" CONSTRAINT "res_partner_res_partner_category_rel_partner_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (partner_id) REFERENCES res_partner(id) ON DELETE CASCADE`. But in the end you have to combine info from the tables and odoo's field definitions (from code or look into the technical model details within odoo).

Comment: One more question. What should I do in case when I have a few categories for one partner? For example, in the Odoo UI, I can create 1 partner but set 2 or more categories for it. In this case, Odoo will create a 1 "res.partner" record, a few "res.partner.category" records for each category, and the same few "res.partner.res.partner.category.rel" records where will be the IDs for each category but only one Id for the partner. So how can I get all IDs of categories related to the target partner?

Comment: JSON-RPC should get you a list/array of `res_partner_category` `id`s (Primary key). Setting a many2many field is a bit complicated ([some doc about that](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command)).

Answer (score 1):

The table name is generated automatically for the [category_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/addons/base/models/res_partner.py#L169) field on `res.partner` model and is it not available in the list of models (`env.keys()`), you can't use it in `orm` methods

To get the list of categories related to one partner, you have to query the `ras.partner` model to get the `category_id` field value, Odoo will return a list of categories IDS as a list